# dji error : Execution could not be executed

Tags: dji-sdk

I have been struggling quiet sometime to be able to understand why I am receiving the error "The execution could not be executed" by the mission manager when trying to create a waypoint mission. I have attached the workflow I am working with, I would really appreciate it if you could take a look at it.

```
1.Initialize FlightController : 
mFlightController = ((Aircraft) product).getFlightController();
    getProductInstance().getGimbal()
                    .rotate(new Rotation.Builder().pitch(-180)
                            .mode(RotationMode.SPEED)
                            .yaw(Rotation.NO_ROTATION)
                            .roll(Rotation.NO_ROTATION)
                            .time(0)
                            .build(), new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResult(DJIError error) {
                                }
                    });
mFlightController.setControlMode(ControlMode.SMART, ... );
mFlightController.setMaxFlightHeight(499.0f , ... );
mFlightController.setMaxFlightRadiusLimitationEnabled(false, ...);
mFlightController.setLandImmediatelyBatteryThreshold(15, ...);
mFlightController.setStateCallback(new FlightControllerState.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onUpdate(@NonNull FlightControllerState flightControllerState) {
        //Check GPS level
    }
}
mFlightController.setHomeLocationUsingAircraftCurrentLocation( ... );



  2. Check Batter status :
getProductInstance().getBattery()
            setStateCallback(new BatteryState.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUpdate(BatteryState djiBatteryState) { ... } ;
    });

    3. initialize Mission Manager : 
mMissionManager = new WapointMissionOperator();
mMissionManager.addListener( listener );
    //LIstener does a couple calculations when reaching a waypoint. 

 4. Camera :
mCamera = getProductInstance().getCamera();
mCamera.setMode(SettingsDefinitions.CameraMode.RECORD_VIDEO, ... );
mCamera.setSystemStateCallback(new SystemState.Callback() { ... });


 5. Creating waypoint mission Builder : 
WaypointMission.Builder builder = new WaypointMission.Builder();
builder.autoFlightSpeed( value );
builder.maxFlightSpeed( value );
builder.setExitMissionOnRCSignalLostEnabled(false);
    builder.finishedAction(WaypointMissionFinishedAction.AUTO_LAND);
    builder.flightPathMode(WaypointMissionFlightPathMode.NORMAL);
    builder.gotoFirstWaypointMode(WaypointMissionGotoWaypointMode.SAFELY);
    builder.headingMode(WaypointMissionHeadingMode.USING_WAYPOINT_HEADING);
    builder.setGimbalPitchRotationEnabled(true);

 6. Creating waypoints : 
    for (int i = 0; i < waypointCount; i++) {
        dji.common.mission.waypoint.Waypoint djiwp = new dji.common.mission.waypoint.Waypoint(lat, lon, alt);
        djiwp.heading = 0; //facing true north
        djiwp.addAction(new WaypointAction(WaypointActionType.STAY, 0)); //just passby 
        builder.addWaypoint(djiwp);
    }

  7. finishing up with builder:
WaypointMission mission = builder.build();

 8. starting mission :
mMissionManager.loadMission(mission);
if (WaypointMissionState.READY_TO_RETRY_UPLOAD.equals(mMissionManager.getCurrentState())
                              ||   WaypointMissionState.READY_TO_UPLOAD.equals(mMissionManager.getCurrentState())) {

    mMissionManager.uploadMission(new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() { ... } );
}
mFlightController.setHomeLocationUsingAircraftCurrentLocation( ... ); //redo just to check.
mFlightController.setConnectionFailSafeBehavior(ConnectionFailSafeBehavior.GO_HOME, ...);
mMissionManager.startMission(new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you get readytoexecute before you try to execute. I was getting a lot of failures before I did that.

Answer (score 1):

From you using MissionManager I assume you are using the 3.x version of DJI SDK.
You should try out the 4.x version. Latest one is 4.3.2.
Mission related features have been revamped and much more stable now.
The point of contact now is MissionControl instead of MissionManager.
Check out the API reference page. It has been revamped as well:
http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Missions/DJIMissionControl.html